# best component for toggling css class in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am making a maze and I need the ability to build the walls of the maze. So I have a 10x10 gridpane and I need to be able to toggle the color of the field in the grid between gray and green. What component would be best for this, button? label? or something else?

Comment: If fields are fixed size, `Rectangle` is fine. `Region` would work as well. `Label` and `Button` would work, too, but it would be an abuse; `Label` is for displaying a text label and `Button` is used to trigger an action.

Comment: yes the fields are all the same size

Comment: Based on the description you gave, I would go with `Rectangle`.